# An unexpected error has occurred while clicking the search option in record list - NetSuite

Tags: customization, netsuite, suitescript

I m trying to click search in a custom record list but system is throwing an unexpected error. I have tried to inactive all the applied scripts, incase if its happening because of them but still the same. can anyone guide me whats the issue.

Once i click the below search option:

[image]

System throws this error:

[image]

This is happening from the search option at the top right is a record as well.
Please suggest any reason of this.

Comment: Odd, the only things I can think of are: (1) confirm the permissions at the Custom record level (typically if using the permissions list "View" access is all that's needed to also search).  (2) confirm the user/role has all applicable search permissions.  For testing purposes, if you are you able to navigate directly to https://ACCOUNT_ID.app.netsuite.com/app/common/search/search.nl?searchtype=Custom&rectype=REC_ID (replacing ACCOUNT_ID and REC_ID), then perhaps there's some sort of restriction at the 1st screenshot you shared.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.
I am trying to search using Administrator role and have even tried pasting the URL but system still shows the same error.

Comment: Agreed, the native Administrator role should have all applicable search permissions to satisfy #2.  Did you confirm #1 (the permissions at the Custom Record level)? Ref Suite Answers 10148 (https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10148), and 65756 (https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/65756).  New solution idea #3: confirm that the fields on the Custom record do not have search restrictions on the Access subtab.  Can reference Suite answer 21035 (https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/21035).